# how to apply two classes of css on same element?

Tags: html, css

i make a textarea and i want if user move another page and textarea empty then message show this field is required,but when i apply class then ckeditor class not apply but i want both classes apply,how i do this?
i try to add both classes seperated with comma but not applying,here is my code:

```
<textarea name="message" class="validate[required] ckeditor" id="message" cols="90" rows="15" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
```

how i apply both classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write it after a space.

**For instance,**

```
<textarea name="message" class="validate ckeditor yourClass" id="message" cols="90" rows="15" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
```

Comment: validate[required] class not applying

Comment: Just write validate. - @Arif

Comment: `[` is not a valid class name character

Comment: Thats correct @tewathia Updated. I rushed with my answer, so did not looked what Arif had written.

Comment: i used your code but not work properly validate class not working

Comment: please write your class name instead of `yourClass` that I have written and give it the property that you want. - @Arif